# how to upload picture and event in my Published App Xcode 6

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, xcode6, mbaas

i am New user for Xcode in swift and i published my app to App Store. i could only connected with Parse ( Push notification Service )

but actually i want in future to change the background of my App or to add New Event. i know it is possible to do all this  things with backend service but i heard that i have to design the code in parse, there is anyway to find the sample codes like push notification in Parse or somewhere else?

i will really appreciate if someone can help me.

Comment: If you don't have the code to change the background of your app or add an event in your app in your published version then you will have to publish an update.

Comment: i want to know for my future app, there is any way to find out the sample of  that code to connect my app with Parse, so in future i can add easily an event when my app published.

Comment: What does `add easily an event when my app published ` mean?

Comment: i mean, if future when i create app i want to connect with parse that i can add An event through parse so it will publish automatically in my app.

Comment: Can you provide an example of an app that does what you mean? It sounds like you want to abstract out [Parse Event](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.Events.html) behavior, which Parse doesn't do for you.

Comment: Hi, here is the link the you can download that App, if you go to eventi they always Add new events, they do this through their server. so i want to do the same like them but with parse server. [ https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/scuola-italiana-di-biogestalt/id927809699?mt=8 ]

Answer (score 0):

"I want in future to change the background of my App or to add New Event"

These are hugely different scenarios.

Its pretty trivial to use Parse to change a screen background. Just save your existing background image as a file (eg as a UIImage) in Parse, and have your app download the image from Parse and set it as the background image of your UIView. Change the file and all users will see a new background. You would need to do this when the app loads (or at least before you access this screen), or else there will be some annoying delay when you access the screen with the new background image.

Adding a new event sounds close to impossible, as it involves modifying your code. But your compiled code is "signed", and as such is designed by Apple to be impossible to change without going through the market. Any app which could do that could bypass the market and potentially directly download malicious code. And nor (as far as I know) does Apple provide any support for extending or changing code within iOS. If its not actually impossible, I expect it would be so difficult and require so much knowledge of iOS as to be infeasible for the average programmer.

EDIT: You have now clarified as to what you mean by "Event" in your comments. This is just data which you load dynamically (and not an "event" in the programming sense). Yes you can do this through Parse (and lots of other ways), just read/load the data through Parse. Very easy to do, have you read Parse's excellent tutorial?

Comment: but when my app Aproved and i want to change some contents, is it possible to do that trough the parse or every time i have to edit my app and resubmit it again?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "contents". If the contents are (for example) background images, then you can do this through Parse (and lots of other ways). If the contents are executable code, you have to resubmit.

Comment: Thanks Peter, i was trying to find tutorial in parse website, i didnt find something explain well, if you have can you share that links?